# How do we print the value of a varible inside the widget?

Tags: flutter, dart

I would like to print the values of boolean inside the widget `Visibility` how can I do it ?

```
Stack(
        children: [
            Scaffold(
                body: Container(
                    //change the margin
                    margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 0, 300),
                    child: 
                    Visibility(
                        visible: mapVisible,

                        // print the value of the boolean mapVisible
                        maintainSemantics: true,
                        maintainInteractivity: true,
                        maintainAnimation: true,
                        maintainState: true,
                        maintainSize: true,
                        replacement: Container(), )
```

Comment: You can not execute any method from inside the widget.

Comment: @kishandhankecha your comment is untrue. Methods can be used to assign values or even just to perform some functionality. It just means that the method will probably get executed every time the widget is built. Which in some cases are completely fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is rather vague. It could be one of 2 things.

1. To print the variable value every time the widget builds you can just move the logic into a method like such.

   ```dart
   bool mapVisible = true;
   Stack(
           children: [
               Scaffold(
                   body: Container(
                       //change the margin
                       margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 0, 300),
                       child: 
                       Visibility(
                           visible: _shouldShow,

                           // print the value of the boolean mapVisible
                           maintainSemantics: true,
                           maintainInteractivity: true,
                           maintainAnimation: true,
                           maintainState: true,
                           maintainSize: true,
                           replacement: Container(), )
   bool _shouldShow()
   {
   print(mapVisible);
   return mapVisible;
   }
   ```
2. or to display the variable as text to the user you can do the following.

   ```dart
   Stack(
           children: [
               Scaffold(
                   body: Container(
                       //change the margin
                       margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 0, 300),
                       child: 
                       Visibility(
                           visible: mapVisible,

                           // print the value of the boolean mapVisible
                           maintainSemantics: true,
                           maintainInteractivity: true,
                           maintainAnimation: true,
                           maintainState: true,
                           maintainSize: true,
                           replacement: Container(),
                           child:Text(mapVisible.toString()),//-->show it a widget
    )
   ```